# Implementing gradient descent in keras

Tags: mlp

for my project, I defined a model with sequential with 3 dense hidden layers with different numbers of neurons in each layer. Then I compiled and built it with an input shape.

My question is, is it possible to get weights (using model.get_weights) and implement gradient descent algorithm and then, set the weights of the model with upgraded weights?